# Add onclick targeted by class

Tags: javascript, onclick

Rather than adding onClick to each and every link as below, is there a cleaner way to target all links (.tabs a) by adding a short script above or below, and how would this be coded? Thanks in advance for all help :)

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#all" onClick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-1" onClick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-2" onClick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about using event bubbling  here, where you attach the event listener to ul and click any li and take action based on the which li is clicked . Check this for details https://dev.to/shimphillip/handing-javascript-events-efficiently-with-bubble-and-capture-4ha5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element with the class via querySelector and then iterate over the children

```
    function onClick() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
    var element = document.querySelector(".tabs");
    element.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    });
```

Comment: I selected this as the answer because it worked, contained the least amount of code, and targeted the .tabs class as requested. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to obtain all of the elements matching a selector and add event listeners to all of them.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul.tabs > li > a').forEach(a => a.addEventListener("click", e=>{
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}));
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><span>Clicking me has no effect</span></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can use event delegation by only adding a single event listener to the parent `<ul>` and checking the event's target to determine if it was an anchor tag.

```js
document.querySelector('ul.tabs').addEventListener("click", e=>{
  if(e.target.matches("li > a")){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><span>Clicking me has no effect</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-2"">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
 [...document.querySelectorAll('.tabs > li > a')].forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListener('click', () => {
     // window.scrollTo(0, 0)
     alert('Hello')
   });
 });
</script>
```

You get all the elements with `document.querySelectorAll('.tabs > li > a')` and then for each elements you add an `click` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Class selector
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("clickMe");

// Function
const fn = () => console.log('click');

// Loop
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', fn, false);
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a data-myattribute="link1" href="#all" class="clickMe">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-myattribute="link2" href="#category-1" class="clickMe">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-myattribute="link3" href="#category-2" class="clickMe">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
```